# for each .txt file line create a new link with .txt file line data in php

Tags: php, loops, count, lines

I would like to create a .php file that will read a .txt file and then for each line in the text file it will take the data and create a new link with the data.

*Example:*

**list.txt**

```
r2389
y3323
u3330
d2723
```

**reader.php**

```
<?php
    $myFile = "list.txt";
    $lines = file($myFile);
?>
<a href="http://website.com/<?php echo $lines[0];?>">link 1</a>
<a href="http://website.com/<?php echo $lines[1];?>">link 2</a>
<a href="http://website.com/<?php echo $lines[2];?>">link 3</a>
<a href="http://website.com/<?php echo $lines[3];?>">link 4</a>
```

**reader.php** output

```
<a href="http://website.com/r2389">link 1</a>
<a href="http://website.com/y3323">link 2</a>
<a href="http://website.com/u3330">link 3</a>
<a href="http://website.com/d2723">link 4</a>
```

This will get the information and then echo it into the link.
But this means I need to create the right amount of links for it to work properly, in the end I want to just be able to edit the **list.txt** and then have the php automatically create a

```
<a href="<?php echo $lines[*];?>">link *</a>
```

depending on the amount of lines in the **list.txt**.
It will also label

```
<a>link *</a>
```

depending on the line number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is your problem in doing so? Right now, you are just asking for someone to do your homework.

Comment: I have tried a few things, which are only doing half the job.. eg, I can get the amount of lines in the txt file but unable to convert that to create new links.. the code i've been using for it is all over the place and not very 'read worthy'.. I'll keep hunting and update the question but my findings so far don't seem valuable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the array.

```
<?php
    $myFile = "list.txt";
    $lines = file($myFile);

    $lineNumber = 1;
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
    ?>
    <a href="http://website.com/<?php echo $line;?>">link <?php echo $lineNumber?></a>
    <?
    $lineNumber++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: for all the time it took me to write the question I almost immediately started trying some which is working out `foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)`. Thankyou nvanesch this has answered my question.

Comment: no problem. But please note that $line_num is the array key. For file(...) it should always be a numeric sequence. but i always hold to the folowing rule: "never expect array keys in php to be in sequence". That is why i do my own counter. It also allows you to filter out some lines without breaking the count.